# How to get rid of Conversion from string "admin" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hello guys am having issues with my login form for multiple users of my software, below is the complete login button code for the admin

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    If cmbusertype.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select the appropriate Account Type!", vbExclamation, "Account Type")
    End If
    If cmbusertype.Text = "Admin" Then
        Dim Strconn As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\phermacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim Selectcmd As String = "select * from tbl_admin where admin_username = '" + txtusername.Text + "' and password = '" + txtpassword.Text + "'"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
        sqlconn = New SqlConnection(Strconn)
        Try
            sqlconn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not connect to DataBase. Application will close now!", vbCritical, "Database Error")
            End
        End Try
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(Selectcmd, sqlconn)
        da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        sqlcmd.Dispose()
        sqlconn.Close()
        da.Fill(ds)
```

Matching Admin User Name & Password

```
 If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    If txtusername.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) And txtpassword.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1) Then
                        MsgBox("Administrator Log-in Successful.", vbInformation, "Admin Log-in")
                        Me.Hide()
                        adminform.Show()

                    Else
                        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtusername, "Invalid User Name.")
                        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtpassword, "Invalid Password.")
                        MsgBox("Invalid Administrator Username or Password.", vbCritical, "Admin Log-in")
                    End If

                Else
                    ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtusername, "Invalid User name or Password.")
                    ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtpassword, "Invalid User name or Password.")
                    ErrorProvider1.SetError(cmbusertype, "Please select the appropriate Account Type")
                    MsgBox("Invalid Administrator Username or Password.", vbCritical, "Admin Log-in")
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

the code line highlighted is the following

```
        If txtusername.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) And txtpassword.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1) Then
```

and the error is "Conversion from string "admin" to type 'Double' is not valid." am actually new to vb trying to create a login for multiple users, the above part as you can see is just for the admin. Please any help here will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: A couple of things you might want to consider: 1. don't store passwords in clear text in the database, hash the password instead, 2. The code above is using string concatenation which is vulnerable to sql injection, read up on it and use parameterized queries instead. Also you are using + for string concatenation in VB, the correct operator is & (ampersand) which is probably the root of your issue

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i've use the & operator and still the issue remains the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this...

```
   Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    If cmbusertype.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select the appropriate Account Type!", vbExclamation, "Account Type")
    End If
    If cmbusertype.Text = "Admin" Then
        Dim Strconn As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\phermacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim Selectcmd As String = "select * from tbl_admin where admin_username = @usernme and password = @paswd"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
        sqlconn = New SqlConnection(Strconn)
        Try
            sqlconn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not connect to DataBase. Application will close now!", vbCritical, "Database Error")
            End
        End Try
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(Selectcmd, sqlconn)
        sqlcmd.parameters.addwithValue("@usernme",txtusername.Text)
        sqlcmd.parameters.addwithValue("@paswd",txtpassword.Text)
        da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        sqlcmd.Dispose()
        sqlconn.Close()
        da.Fill(ds)
```

Comment: @downvoter Thanks for your response. can you explain why?

Comment: @GEORGESUTER As Charleh suggested, Your code is advantage for SQL Injection, to avoid that use parameterized queries as i updated.. Give a try and let me know if any errors...

Comment: Thanks so much Still the issue remains the same Sankar Raj

Comment: @GEORGESUTER Did check the code with break point? check the `ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)` what it returns?

Comment: Since you are selecting the entire row. try with the column name instead of colmun index. For ex : `If txtusername.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("columnname") And txtpassword.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("columnname") Then`

Comment: Thanks alot  Sankar Raj I try using the column name and works fine, thanks alot.

Comment: It's logging in but am still having an exception on this line" adminform.Show()" Object variable or With block variable not set. Any belp with that?

Comment: Replace `Me.Hide()` with `Me.visible=false`... Try it

Comment: found the error I was calling with wrong form name its fixed now thank you very much.

Comment: Ideally answers should be an explanation of the problem and solution rather than just the code, this is after all a learning resource